# Is there anyway for a CSV file to declare how it was delimited?

Tags: csv

Is there anyway for a CSV file to declare how it was delimited so that the program opening it knows how to format it?

Comment: Properly, a `.CSV` should use commas as separators, while a `.TSV` would use tabs, but there is no strong definition as others have stated. I've found [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) informative.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Excel it will recognize this declaration at the beginning of the file:

```
sep=,
```

[taken from this superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/530407)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Also, CSV file format is only a Psuedo-format so there is no formal specification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Answer (score 0):

No, you might have better luck with "ASCII Delimited Text" https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/

There is also Arff format which is very similar and let you define the column
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html